# Would Robin Hood be ethical in Kantian ethics?

Tags: ethics, kant

> In order for an action to have moral worth, it must be done from the
>   motive of duty.

Would Robin Hood be ethical, **assuming that he has no other intent only acted out of the duty to help others**, and not out of inclination that would give him any sense of gratification?

Comment: In the *Metaphysics of Morals* it is made quite clear that even if the state in his actions and laws is immoral, political opposition is the way to go. He condemns vigilante behaviour in general.

Answer (score 2):

Kant's categorical imperative states

*Act only according to that maxim whereby you can at the same time will that it should become a universal law*

"Acting out of the duty to help others" without any other intent satisfies Kant's maxim. Hence it is ethical in the Kantian sense.

Aside: I'm no competent to make out whether the above maxim was actually the intent of Robin Hood as portrayed by the English folklore.

Comment: "Acting out of the duty to help others" without asking if they are interested in getting the help or consulting them about the methods is not something one can reasonably will to universalize. In any case, Kant's positions are far too complex to be extracted out of his slogany formulas, see e.g. virmaior's answer to [Is Kant's ethical theory adequate to the complexities of universalisation?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/48984/9148)

Comment: @Conifold I prefer to stay away from adding casuistry to general principles. I have confidence in identifying in a concrete situation what has to be done or has to be omitted to help the person in question. - I did not get the point in virmaior's answer you refer to. Possibly you could state a separate answer to the OP's question. Then we can better discuss the issue.