# Given there are many relevant act descriptions, how can anyone obey the moral law?

Tags: kant

> we end up with either multiple maxims to test (and the possibility of conflicting results) or a single “relevant” maxim... [universalisability] should not be viewed as testing the actual maxims on which agents might act in some specific context... [we] should be seen as working with “generic” maxims, which can apply to
> many different actions, and more than one of which may apply in a
> specific instance (Herman 1996, ch. 7).

So Kant does not prove "maxims on which agents might act... [because?] more than one... may apply in a specific instance"

https://www.josephulatowski.net/post/kant-on-the-problem-of-relevant-descriptions-and-the-problem-of-act-individuation

So how do we obey the moral law? I may have misunderstood, in which case, given you can understand how, can you explain why?

Comment: This is known as the problem of relevant descriptions and it is already discussed in [Is Kant's ethical theory adequate to the complexities of universalisation?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/48984/9148) and [What are some examples of categorical imperatives/universalizable maxims relevant to modern ethics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/47559/9148) Roughly, the Kantian answer is that one is supposed to act in good faith instead of shopping for self-serving maxims and redescriptions.

Comment: ok so the question should be closed @Conifold ?

Comment: what do you mean by the phrase "in good faith", sinvcerely and without self deception @Conifold it's not quite the same question, not unless the answer to the relevat descriptor is *whatever motivates us*, which the link suggests is not a popular take

Comment: It reminds me of Jesus' answer when asked about all the behavioral laws and rules.

Comment: i don't actually know what you refer to, but it sounds interesting @ScottRowe

Comment: He said (abbreviated) 1. Love God. 2. Love your neighbor as yourself. And then said that it was all that is needed to fulfill the (spiritual) Law. So, it pivots on the *in good faith* precept. Inescapable.